# Excel 2016 compare 2 string columns (true or false) returns -1

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm a limited Excel user so I don't understand this.  In Excel 2016 I'm comparing 2 string columns with this formula:

```
=if(I2=R2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

It has worked fine on many pages in the workbook.  Now I've come to a page (same workbook) where this formula returns -1 instead of TRUE.

Why is this?

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you don't need the "if": `I2=R2` already returns true or false.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie: I tried your version of the formula and it worked.  Strange that I have a page where my formula didn't work.  I don't use Excel much but I'd still like to know why.